# Spark 1.4.1: Issue when reading MySQL BigInt columns

Tags: mysql, apache-spark

When reading MySQL columns that are of type `BigInt` (e.g. `BIGINT(21) UNSIGNED` below), Spark cannot cast `java.math.BigDecimal` to a `String` in the following snippet:

```
val driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
val server = ...
val infoSchema = "INFORMATION_SCHEMA"
val port = 3306
val user = ...
val pw = ...
val dbUrl = s"jdbc:mysql://$server:$port/$infoSchema"

val dbProperties = new java.util.Properties()
dbProperties.setProperty("driver", driver)
dbProperties.setProperty("user", user)
dbProperties.setProperty("password", pw)

val schema = ...
val table = ...

val cols = sqlContext.read.jdbc(dbUrl, "COLUMNS", dbProperties)
  .filter(col("TABLE_SCHEMA") === schema && col("TABLE_NAME") === table)
  .map(_.getValuesMap[String](Seq("ORDINAL_POSITION", "COLUMN_NAME")))
  .collect()
  .toList

cols.map(e => e("COLUMN_NAME"))
cols.map(e => e("ORDINAL_POSITION")) // java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

However, when I do the following, there is no issue:

```
val num = new java.math.BigDecimal(1)
num.toString
```

Is this a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Row.getValuesMap[T]` is not used for type casting. Instead it explicitly states that values are of type `T` (internally it is just a `get` followed `asInstanceOf[T]`) and `BigDecimal` is clearly not a `String`.

You could:

- Add implicit conversion.
- Use `_.getValuesMap[Any]`.
- Use SQL cast before mapping.

  ```
  withColumn("ORDINAL_POSITION", $"ORDINAL_POSITION".cast(StringType))
  ```

but to be honest honest all these options are rather ugly it makes more sense to extract values directly:

```
sqlContext.read.jdbc(...).filter(...)
  .select("ORDINAL_POSITION", "COLUMN_NAME")
  .rdd
  .map { case Row(i: java.math.BigDecimal, c: String) => (i, c) }
```